# Swift Mapkit, How to add tap gesture in custom annotation?

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is CustomAnnotation {
      let annotation = annotation as! CustomAnnotation
      let annotationView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotation.identifier!) ?? MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotation.identifier!)

      annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = "photoCluster"

      annotationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      let gesture = CustomTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchAction))
      annotationView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

      return annotationView
    }
}
```

Above code is custom annotation init code. but gesture event is not triggered. On the other hand,

```
let clusterView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "clusterView")
        ?? MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "clusterView")
      clusterView.annotation = cluster

let gesture = CustomTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchAction))   

clusterView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

cluster annotation(MKClusterAnnotation) is triggered by gesture.

What should do I do for triggering single annotation by touching?

- Solving Code

```
annotationView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
```

Comment: I solved it. It's my fault. AnnotationView needs a frame size.